# how to create a widget which is grouped listview with sticky header and scrollbar and have jumpto index facility available?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

I'm working on flutter list view, but I want it grouped list view with sticky header, side scrollbar and scroll to item (must provide jump to element, not particular on grouped) and that list view element have dynamic height and list may be long (10000 elements).
Basically, like whatsapp chat which is grouped by date with 2 additionally feature.

1. side scrollbar (not like whatsapp which is goes up and down)
2. jump to list view element (not scroll one by one) (element hv dynamic height).

I already tried flutter available library "scroll_to_index", "sticky_grouped_list", "scrollable_positioned_list" and many more, but none of them give desired output.
Please help me out, Thanks in advance.